# AFIncrementalStore and accessing API URL such as http://apiurl.com/users/1/posts

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afincrementalstore

I've looked the the examples included on AFIncreementalStore's gitHub page and think I understand the process of requesting objects from a remote api from a URL like http://apiurl.com/users. Basically I would, in a UsersListViewController for example, do this:

```
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"User"];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"userID" ascending:YES]];
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO;

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[(id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    [_fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get something like "posts" from a url such as http://apiurl.com/users/1/posts.

My initial thought is I add a predicate to the fetch request:

```
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Post"];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"createdAt" ascending:YES]];
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userID == %@", userID];        
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[(id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    [_fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
```

Will adding this predicate generate a GET request using this URL (assuming the userID I used in the predicate is 1)? http://apiurl.com/users/1/posts